# Reading Consumer Price Index data in R?

Tags: r

I need to read the data from this link http://www.bls.gov/cpi/cpifiles/cpiai.txt into a data frame. Sadly the data is not in a csv file. What is the best way of doing it?

I tried

```
cpiai <- read.table("http://www.bls.gov/cpi/cpifiles/cpiai.txt")
```

Thanks!

Comment: You just need to set `skip` and `sep`options according to your file

Comment: You can try `read.fwf`, but this also looks like it's in good enough shape that you should be able to just use `read.table` (as mentioned, above, making use of `skip` and other relevant arguments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sticking to read.table:

```
path<-"http://www.bls.gov/cpi/cpifiles/cpiai.txt"
cpiai <- read.table(path,header=T,fill=TRUE,skip=16)

>head(cpiai)
  Year Jan. Feb. Mar. Apr.  May June July Aug. Sep. Oct. Nov. Dec. Avg.  Dec  Avg
1 1913  9.8  9.8  9.8  9.8  9.7  9.8  9.9  9.9 10.0 10.0 10.1 10.0  9.9   NA   NA
2 1914 10.0  9.9  9.9  9.8  9.9  9.9 10.0 10.2 10.2 10.1 10.2 10.1 10.0  1.0  1.0
3 1915 10.1 10.0  9.9 10.0 10.1 10.1 10.1 10.1 10.1 10.2 10.3 10.3 10.1  2.0  1.0
4 1916 10.4 10.4 10.5 10.6 10.7 10.8 10.8 10.9 11.1 11.3 11.5 11.6 10.9 12.6  7.9
5 1917 11.7 12.0 12.0 12.6 12.8 13.0 12.8 13.0 13.3 13.5 13.5 13.7 12.8 18.1 17.4
6 1918 14.0 14.1 14.0 14.2 14.5 14.7 15.1 15.4 15.7 16.0 16.3 16.5 15.1 20.4 18.0
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by J.R. gives you all you need to know, but just to be complete, also consider access via Quandl which curates the data *and* also gives you a unified (free) API across the millions of series they track.

For this CPI the page is https://www.quandl.com/FRED/CPIAUCSL-Consumer-Price-Index-for-All-Urban-Consumers-All-Items-USA-Inflation and access is as easy as

```
R> library(Quandl)
R> dat <- Quandl("FRED/CPIAUCSL")
R> head(dat)
        Date   Value
1 2014-09-01 237.633
2 2014-08-01 237.428
3 2014-07-01 237.909
4 2014-06-01 237.693
5 2014-05-01 237.083
6 2014-04-01 236.254
R>
```