# Compute deflation factor to index wages, by CPI, in panel data

Tags: r, panel-data

I'm struggling to understand exactly how to compute a deflation factor for wages in a panel based on inflation.

I've an R example below to help me illustrate the issue.

In Wooldridge (2009:452) Introductory Econometrics, 5th ed., he creates a *deflation factor* by dividing 107.6 by 65.2, i.e. 107.6/65.2 ≈ 1.65, but I can't figure out to to apply this to my own panel data. Wooldridge only mentions the *deflation factor* in passing.

Say I have a mini panel with two people, *Jane* and *Tom*, starting from 2006/2009 and running until 2015 with their yearly wage,

```
# install.packages(c("dplyr"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(2)
tbl <- tibble(id = rep(c('Jane', 'Tom'), c(7, 10)),
       yr = c(2009:2015, 2006:2015),
       wg = c(rnorm(7, mean=5.1*10^4, sd=9), rnorm(10, 4*10^4, 12))
       ); tbl

#>  A tibble: 17 x 3
#>       id    yr       wg
#>    <chr> <int>    <dbl>
#>  1  Jane  2009 50991.93
#>  2  Jane  2010 51001.66
#>  3  Jane  2011 51014.29
#>  4  Jane  2012 50989.83
#>  5  Jane  2013 50999.28
#>  6  Jane  2014 51001.19
#>  7  Jane  2015 51006.37
#>  8   Tom  2006 39997.12
#>  9   Tom  2007 40023.81
#> 10   Tom  2008 39998.33
#> 11   Tom  2009 40005.01
#> 12   Tom  2010 40011.78
#> 13   Tom  2011 39995.29
#> 14   Tom  2012 39987.52
#> 15   Tom  2013 40021.39
#> 16   Tom  2014 39972.27
#> 17   Tom  2015 40010.54
```

I now get the consumer price index (CPI) (using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26741947/1305688))

```
# install.packages(c("Quandl"), dependencies = TRUE)
CPI00to16 <- Quandl::Quandl("FRED/CPIAUCSL", collapse="annual",
                 start_date="2000-01-01", end_date="2016-01-01")
as_tibble(CPI00to16)
#> # A tibble: 17 x 2
#>          Date   Value
#>        <date>   <dbl>
#>  1 2016-12-31 238.106
#>  2 2015-12-31 237.846
#>  3 2014-12-31 236.290
#>  4 2013-12-31 234.723
#>  5 2012-12-31 231.221
#>  6 2011-12-31 227.223
#>  7 2010-12-31 220.472
#>  8 2009-12-31 217.347
#>  9 2008-12-31 211.398
#> 10 2007-12-31 211.445
#> 11 2006-12-31 203.100
#> 12 2005-12-31 198.100
#> 13 2004-12-31 191.700
#> 14 2003-12-31 185.500
#> 15 2002-12-31 181.800
#> 16 2001-12-31 177.400
#> 17 2000-12-31 174.600
```

My question is how do I deflate *Jane* and *Tom*'s wages cf. Wooldridge 2009 selecting 2015 as the baseline year?

### Update

Following [MrSmithGoesToWashington’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9088378/mrsmithgoestowashington) below:

```
CPI00to16$yr <- as.numeric(format(CPI00to16$Date,'%Y'))
CPI00to16 <- mutate(CPI00to16, deflation_factor = CPI00to16[2,2]/Value)

df <- tbl %>% inner_join(as_tibble(CPI00to16[,3:4]), by = "yr")
df <- mutate(df, wg_defl = deflation_factor*wg, wg_diff = wg_defl-wg)
df

#> # A tibble: 17 x 6
#>       id    yr       wg deflation_factor  wg_defl   wg_diff
#>    <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>            <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1  Jane  2009 50991.93         1.094315 55801.21 4809.2844
#>  2  Jane  2010 51001.66         1.078804 55020.78 4019.1176
#>  3  Jane  2011 51014.29         1.046751 53399.28 2384.9910
#>  4  Jane  2012 50989.83         1.028652 52450.80 1460.9728
#>  5  Jane  2013 50999.28         1.013305 51677.83  678.5477
#>  6  Jane  2014 51001.19         1.006585 51337.04  335.8494
#>  7  Jane  2015 51006.37         1.000000 51006.37    0.0000
#>  8   Tom  2006 39997.12         1.171078 46839.76 6842.6394
#>  9   Tom  2007 40023.81         1.124860 45021.18 4997.3691
#> 10   Tom  2008 39998.33         1.125110 45002.53 5004.1909
#> 11   Tom  2009 40005.01         1.094315 43778.07 3773.0575
#> 12   Tom  2010 40011.78         1.078804 43164.86 3153.0747
#> 13   Tom  2011 39995.29         1.046751 41865.12 1869.8369
#> 14   Tom  2012 39987.52         1.028652 41133.26 1145.7322
#> 15   Tom  2013 40021.39         1.013305 40553.87  532.4863
#> 16   Tom  2014 39972.27         1.006585 40235.49  263.2225
#> 17   Tom  2015 40010.54         1.000000 40010.54    0.0000
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "deflate" (`cumprod`?), but if you can describe in terms of mathematical operations what you want to do, I can help you do it.

Comment: He uses the december index of 1978 (65.2) and 1985 (107.6). cf [Here](http://www.usinflationcalculator.com/inflation/consumer-price-index-and-annual-percent-changes-from-1913-to-2008/). So you have to do the same with the index of the convenient date for your purpose.

Comment: Oh sorry, it was the average index over the year ..

Comment: That is very helpful. So, he simply takes _baseline year_, i.e. 1978 (65.2), and divides it with the year to deflate, i.e. 1985 (107.6). So, as I want to have 2015 (237.846) as baseline year I would simply take the vector `Value` and divide it by year 2015 (237.846), i.e. `deflation_factor <- CPI00to16$Value/CPI00to16[2,2]` and then multiply that vector with  `deflation_factor*tbl$wg`?

Comment: After you update I'm not sure if you still have a question or not. If you do still have a question, please make it clearer. If not, please post your answer as an answer, not as part of the question.

Comment: @Gregor, I posted it like this allow for one of the helpful commentator to post an answer and get the credit for that.